# Counting relationships size in Neo4j

Tags: twitter, neo4j

I have a Neo4j Graph database which stores Twitter data.
Each `Tweet` is about a `Topic` and has got this kind of relationship:

```
(t:Tweet)-[:ABOUT]->(t1:Topic)
```

A `User` can be mentioned by a `Tweet` due to this relationship
`(t:Tweet)-[:MENTIONS]->(u:User)`

I'd like to know **how many users are mentioned in tweets regarding a specific topic**.

My query is:

```
match (n:Topic)<--()-[r:MENTIONS]->(u:User) 
where n.name='politics'
return count(r)
```

Is this query right? Because I've got unexpected results.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would want to return the topic as well, i.e. use `return n, count(r)`. Neo4j. Unlike SQL though, Cypher handles [aggregations](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating) implicitly, so it will figure out that the data should be aggregated for each Topic `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the following query.

```
match (n:Topic{name:'politics'}) 
RETURN size((n)<--()-[:MENTIONS]->(:User)) as count
```